# How can we determine if an equation represents a travelling wave?

Tags: waves

Are there any particular conditions for a wave equation to represent a travelling wave? If yes, are they more than one?
As an example could you please explain if $y=\dfrac{1}{x+vt}$ represents or does not represent a travelling wave?

Comment: I do not understand why this question has been considered as a homework-like question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the graph of your function has an infinite spike located at $x=-vt$. If $t$ is time, and $v$ is positive, the spike is moving to left at speed $|v|$. Usually we call any $f(x-vt)$ or $f(x+vt)$ a wave as it is is a solution to the wave equation ---  but perhaps we make a physical assumption that $f$ is well-behaved to be a solution to a physics problem. In this case whether we should regard such a travelling spike  as a "wave" is best left to the lawyers to argue about.

Answer (score 1):

Every wave must satisfy the [wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation). The wave equation is an important second-order linear partial differential equation for the description of waves—as they occur in classical physics—such as mechanical waves (e.g. water waves, sound waves, and seismic waves) or light waves. It arises in fields like acoustics, electromagnetics, and fluid dynamics.

In one-dimensional case, It's given by
$$\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial t^2}=v^2\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}$$

This equation is typically described as having only one space dimension $x$ because the only other independent variable is the time $t$. Nevertheless, the dependent variable $\psi$ may represent a second spatial dimension, if, for example, the displacement $\psi$ takes place in the y-direction, as in the case of a string that is located in the x–y plane.

---

The general solution of this equation is given by
$$\psi(x,t)=\psi_1(x-vt)+\psi_2(x+vt)$$

In other words, solutions of the 1D wave equation are sums of a right traveling function $\psi_1$ and a left traveling function $\psi_2$. "Traveling" means that the shape of these individual arbitrary functions with respect to $x$ stays constant, however, the functions are translated left and right with time at the speed $v$.